# Format currency in textfield in Swift on input

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to format currency input in a textfield in Swift as the user inputs it.

So far, I can only format it successfully when the user finishes inputting:

```
@IBAction func editingEnded(sender: AnyObject) {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    var numberFromField = NSString(string: textField.text).doubleValue

    textField.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)
}
```

However, I would like for the currency to be formatted the moment the user inputs it. When I try to do it on the TextField actions "Editing Changed" or "Value Changed", I can only enter 1 number (if I enter 8, it becomes $8.00) but then once I enter a second number everything goes to $0.00 and I cannot enter further beyond that.

Any suggestions? I feel like this should be an easy fix but I can't quite get at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I modified the function from earlier today.  Works great for "en_US" and "fr_FR".  However, for "ja_JP", the division by 100 I do to create decimals is a problem.  You will need to have a switch or if/else statement that separates currencies with decimals and those that do not have them when formatted by the formatter.  But I think this gets you in the space you wanted to be.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var currentString = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.delegate = self
    }

    //Textfield delegates
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { // return NO to not change text

        switch string {
        case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
            currentString += string
            println(currentString)
            formatCurrency(string: currentString)
        default:
            var array = Array(string)
            var currentStringArray = Array(currentString)
            if array.count == 0 && currentStringArray.count != 0 {
                currentStringArray.removeLast()
                currentString = ""
                for character in currentStringArray {
                    currentString += String(character)
                }
                formatCurrency(string: currentString)
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func formatCurrency(#string: String) {
        println("format \(string)")
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        var numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)/100
        textField.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)
        println(textField.text )
    }
}
```

Comment: תודה לך! Awesome Steve, you've saved me again. Just a quick question, do you think there's a way to allow it so that when a user enters a number, it is a whole number until they enter the decimal? Like, say they enter 8, the output will be "$8.00" , and then a 9 : "$89.00", and until they enter a decimal, the numbers remain whole?

Comment: what happen when user press back button,
i try after press back button, text will come again and start with where it's left,
any idea to track backsapce button event

Comment: With Swift 2.0 this lines:
            var array = Array(string)
            var currentStringArray = Array(currentString)

Needs to be like:
            var array = Array(string.characters)
            var currentStringArray = Array(currentString.characters)

Comment: You can make the division by 100 general by instead using..

/ pow(10.0, Double(formatter.maximumFractionDigits))

Answer (score 8):

this works for me using NSNumberFormatter...

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Construct the text that will be in the field if this change is accepted
    var oldText = textField.text as NSString
    var newText = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string) as NSString!
    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
    var digitText = ""
    for c in newTextString.unicodeScalars {
        if digits.longCharacterIsMember(c.value) {
            digitText.append(c)
        }
    }

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    var numberFromField = (NSString(string: digitText).doubleValue)/100
    newText = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)

    textField.text = newText

    return false
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. The approved solution above had an issue with the backspace button for me.

Comment: This works great, however, not for currency which add a text behind the number. E.g. Swedish, Norwegian, Danish ect which will show `10 000,00 SEK`, you cannot remove anything.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Robert answer. Updated for **Swift 2.0**

```
//Textfield delegates
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { // return NO to not change text

    switch string {
    case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
        currentString += string
        formatCurrency(currentString)
    default:
        if string.characters.count == 0 && currentString.characters.count != 0 {
            currentString = String(currentString.characters.dropLast())
            formatCurrency(currentString)
        }
    }
    return false
}

func formatCurrency(string: String) {
    print("format \(string)")
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)/100
    self.amountField.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)
    print(self.amountField.text )
}
```

Comment: I was confused as to why this answer said  "RM" in front of the dollar amount, just change "en_MY" to "en_US"

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.0

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        // Construct the text that will be in the field if this change is accepted

        switch string {
        case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
            currentString += string
            formatCurrency(currentString)
        default:
            if string.characters.count == 0 && currentString.characters.count != 0 {
                currentString = String(currentString.characters.dropLast())
                formatCurrency(currentString)
            }
        }
        return false    }

    func formatCurrency(_ string: String) {
        print("format \(string)")
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = findLocaleByCurrencyCode("NGN")
        let numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)/100
        let temp = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: numberFromField))
        self.amountTextField.text = String(describing: temp!.characters.dropFirst())
    }

func findLocaleByCurrencyCode(_ currencyCode: String) -> Locale? {

    let locales = Locale.availableIdentifiers 
    var locale: Locale?     
    for   localeId in locales {     
      locale = Locale(identifier: localeId)     
      if let code = (locale! as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.currencyCode) as? String { 
        if code == currencyCode {
                return locale       
        }   
    } 
}    
return locale }
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a normal currency format ( eg 1 is as $1.00, 88885 is as $8,8885.00 and 7555.8569 as $7,555.86.

```
@IBAction func lostpropertyclicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    var currentString = ""
    currentString = amountTF.text
    formatCurrency(string: currentString)
}

func formatCurrency(#string: String) {
    println("format \(string)")
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    var numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)
    currentString = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
    println(currentString )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { // return NO to not change text

    switch string {
    case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
        currentString += string
        formatCurrency(string: currentString)
    default:
        if string.count == 0 && currentString.count != 0 {
            currentString = String(currentString.dropLast())
            formatCurrency(string: currentString)
        }
    }
    return false
}

func formatCurrency(string: String) {
    print("format \(string)")
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)/100
    //replace billTextField with your text field name
    self.billTextField.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: numberFromField))
    print(self.billTextField.text ?? "" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Naming of the variables need to be improved though. Multiplying by 10 was easy but figuring out how to divide by 10 and round down was tricky with the pointers.

```
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency


    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == amountTextField {
        guard let text = textField.text else {return true}

        let oldDigits = numberFormatter.number(from: text) ?? 0
        var digits = oldDigits.decimalValue

        if let digit = Decimal(string: string) {
            let newDigits: Decimal = digit / 100

            digits *= 10
            digits += newDigits
        }
        if range.length == 1 {
            digits /= 10
            var result = Decimal(integerLiteral: 0)
            NSDecimalRound(&result, &digits, 2, Decimal.RoundingMode.down)
            digits = result
        }

        textField.text = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: digits as NSDecimalNumber, number: .currency)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```