# Changing return type to a decimal?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-extensions

I am trying to convert the current values that I am dealing with to hundredths. Here is my code:

```
extension String {
    var value: Int {
        if let found = Array("abc".characters).indexOf(Character(lowercaseString)) {
            return found + 1
        }
        return 0
    }
    var totalValue: Int {
        var result = 0
        for letter in self.characters {
            result += String(letter).value
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

So the letter a would = .01, the letter b would = .02, and the letter c would = .03

How would I modify my code so this can happen?

**EDIT**

This is the code I am using:

```
@IBAction func sum(sender: AnyObject) {
    strValue.text = String(format: "%.2f", "$\(strInput.text!.value.description)")
}
```

I have no idea if this is the right way to do it but there it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alphabet characters to number values: use pattern matching

If you want to allow this kind of letter -> decimal value conversion only for the letters of the alphabet, it could be appropriate to use pattern matching for the unicode scalars of characters `"a"` to `"z"`.

Note also that the `Character` initializer by `String` will cause a fatal runtime error if called with a `String` instance that contains more than a single graphene cluster (e.g. `"ab".value` in your code example will yield such an error). Hence, it's appropriate to ascertain that `.value` is only ever actually "usable" for single-character strings; returning, say, value `0` for anything but single-character strings with characters of the alphabet.

Finally, `Float` is just a number and will always be displayed as accurate as possible (limited by floating point precision), however without redundant decimals, which is the reasons why the exact value of e.g. `1/10` is displayed as `0.1` and not `0.10`. To control the number of decimals to display, you need to convert the float to a `String` where you can specify the formatting in this conversion, e.g. by the `String(format:)` initializer, or e.g. using an `NSNumberFormatter`.

**Alternative #1: several `String` extensions as in your own example**

Below follows a `String` extension example of using pattern matching to extract the `Float` `.value` property of (single) letters in the alphabet, including also the `String` representation of such a value, called by `.valueAsString` (same for `totalValue`; `totalValueAsString`).

```
/* Alternative #1 */
extension String {

    var value: Float {
        guard case let uc = lowercaseString.unicodeScalars where uc.count == 1,
            let uc1 = uc.first where UnicodeScalar("a")..."z" ~= uc1 else {
            return 0
        }
        
        return Float(uc1.value-96)/100
    }
    
    var valueAsString: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", self.value)
    }
    
    var totalValue: Float {
        var result: Float = 0
        for letter in self.characters {
            result += String(letter).value
        }
        return result
    }
    
    var totalValueAsString: String {
        return String(format: "%.2f", self.totalValue)
    }
    
}

/* example usage */
"a".valueAsString // 0.01
"b".valueAsString // 0.02
"j".valueAsString // 0.10
"abcn".totalValueAsString // 0.20
```

**Alternative #2: condensed pattern matching**

If you're, however, only interested in the "total value" of a `String` of character (filtering out non-alphabetic characters) you could directly apply the pattering matching as a filter to the full string, without the need of using the intermediate `.value` extension, e.g.:

```
/* Alternative #2 */
extension String {
    
    var totalValueAsString: String {
        let pattern = UnicodeScalar("a")..."z"
        let filteredSum = self.lowercaseString.unicodeScalars
            .filter { pattern ~= $0 }
            .reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value - 96 }
        return String(format: "%.2f", Float(filteredSum)/100)
    }
}

/* example usage */
"abc[n".totalValueAsString // 0.20 (ignoring the non-alphabetic "[" character)
```

---

### Applying the above to your specific `sum(...)` function

Now, w.r.t. your edit

> ```
> @IBAction func sum(sender: AnyObject) {
>     strValue.text = String(format: "%.2f", "$\(strInput.text!.value.description)")
> }
> ```

Note that

- You should avoid using the forced unwrapping operator (`!`) on the `.text` property of the (assumed to be) `UITextField` `strInput`, in case this is `nil.
- The `.text` property of `strInput` is a `String`, whereas the `String(format:)` initializer expects an `Float` as its second argument.

Hence, what you're looking for in the `sum(...)` function is most likely something more along the lines of

```
@IBAction func sum(sender: AnyObject) {
    var decText : String = ""
    if let input = strInput.text {
        decText = input.totalValueAsString
    }
    else {
        decText = "0.00"
    }
    strValue.text = "$" + decText
}
```

Given that you are using one of the two `String` extension alternatives above.

---

Finally, for displaying currency in the general context of `UITextFields`, see e.g. the following Q&A:

- [How to input currency format on a text field (from right to left) using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift)

Comment: Thank you very much. Alternative 2 works especially well!

Comment: @Bigfoot11 Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the return value of `value` by 100?

```
extension String {
    var value: Float {
        if let found = Array("abc".characters).indexOf(Character(lowercaseString)) {
            return (Float(found + 1) / 100)
        }
        return 0
    }
    var totalValue: Float {
        var result: Float = 0
        for letter in self.characters {
            result += Float(String(letter).value)
        }
        return result
    }
}

"a".value // 0.01
"b".value // 0.02
"c".value // 0.03
"abc".totalValue // 0.06
```

To show each value with three decimal places, use a format String:

```
String(format: "%.3f", "a".value) // "0.010"
```

or with two decimal places:

```
String(format: "%.2f", 0.1) // 0.10
```

Comment: Perfect! I will accept the answer but just one question. How would I make it so when the value is (f.e. 0.3) it would show it as 0.30? How do I show that second decimal place no matter what the number is?

Comment: @Bigfoot11 You asked for values to be hundredths, not tenths.  Do you mean how would you show 0.03 as 0.030?  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: No I am using a text field and if I were to click a ten times, it would only show up as 0.1 not 0.10. How do I show that extra decimal place even if it as no value?

Comment: @Bigfoot11 edited my answer to show how to use 2 or 3 decimal places with a format String.

Comment: where would I put that code? And, will it apply to all the possible values?

Comment: @Bigfoot11 You would set the format string to the `text` value of your `UITextField`.  Something like this `textField.text = String(format: "%.2f", "a".value)` // "0.01".

Comment: It isn't working. I put in the code but It is showing completely random numbers

Comment: What "isn't working?"  That means something else is wrong.  Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: @Bigfoot11 If it's showing random numbers that means you have a bug elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Note that the above (as well as OP:s code) yields a runtime exception for e.g. `ab.value`, as the `Character` by `String` initializer only allows strings with a single graphene cluster. It would probably be more appropriate to make sure that `self` when calling `.value` is of a single character, and if not, return `nil`/`0`/etc.

Comment: As soon as I modified my code with what you said, it was giving weird numbers. I think there is an error in the code I am using and edited into the question