# required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) not called

Tags: swift, init, nscoder

I wrote my own Button,Textfield, ..., classes. In the storyboard in "Custom Class" I set the class to the UIElement. This works very well.

Now I needed a toolbar that is added programatically. When I add the Toolbar in my ViewController everything is fine. But I want to create my own toolbar class like this.

```
class MyOwnToolbar : UIToolbar {


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //never called
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
   //error: super.init isn'T called on all paths before returning from initiliazer
}
```

In my ViewController I try to call like this:

```
fromToolBar = MyOwnToolBar() //call nothing?
fromToolBar = MyOwnToolBar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)) //doesn't work because init(frame: CGRECT) doesnt work
```

Old code in my ViewController that worked:

```
    self.untilToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,0,0))
    untilToolBar?.backgroundColor = redColor
    untilToolBar?.tintColor = greenColor
    untilToolBar?.barTintColor = blueColor
```

So I could use my working solution, but I want to unterstand why my code isn't working. So maybe somebody have a solution or good links.

Comment: You need to customize it inside awakeFromNib method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score 6):

It is depending how do you create you're `MyOwnToolbar` if you add this in interface builder and connect class to the UI element use method `initWithCoder`

If you're creating your `MyOwnToolbar` programmatically, you should use `init` or `initWithFrame`.

Example:

```
class MyOwnToolbar: UIToolbar {

      private func initialize() {
          self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
          self.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
          self.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      }

      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          initialize()
      }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oleg got it right, if you use storyboard or a xib to create your view controller, then `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will be called.

But you are building your view controller programmatically, so `init(frame: CGRect)` will be called instead of `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

you should override `init(frame: CGRect)`:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```