# How can I remove certain characters from a string using a single line of code?

Tags: swift3, character

I'm looking for a way to remove dollar signs, commas and periods using a single line of code (I'm able to do it using replacingOccurrences 3x). I found trimmingCharacters(:_) but for some reason it doesn't remove commas and periods (at least not all the time).

This is what I get in Xcode 8.1 playground:

```
var myString = "$3,000.50"

myString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "$.,")) //"3,000.50"

myString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: myString)) //""
```

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: `remove dollar signs, commas and periods` So, the expected result should be "300050", right?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`trimmingCharacters(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643030-trimmingcharacters) – it only removes characters from the *ends* of the string.

Comment: @EricAya Yes. That's the expected result.

Comment: @Hamish The documentations saids both ends of the string, so it should work. I just tested by changing myString to "hello" and change the CharacterSet to "he" and confirmed the remaining string is "llo".

Comment: @jackngai Your first example works for "$" because it's at the start of the string, and doesn't work for "," and "." which are *not* at the start or end of the string - as expected. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Comment: @EricAya I switched the CharacterSet to ",$." (so the $ is not on either end) and the $ is still the only character that was removed.

Comment: @EricAya I think I'm getting an idea of how this method works. If I change myString is "$$$$.,500,00,,,,", it will remove each character from both ends that is part of the CharacterSet, and then stops when it finds one that doesn't match, leaving me with "500,00". So this method won't do what I need. But thanks for helping me understand it.

Comment: @LeoDabus I essentially distilled the code from your post to this: `extension String {
    var numbers: String { return components(separatedBy: Numbers.characterSet.inverted).joined() }
    var integer: Int { return Int(numbers) ?? 0 }
}

struct Numbers { static let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789") }

extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}`  While it is not a single line, it does do what I need. So thanks for this.