# Best way to validate a number input in iOS?

Tags: ios, numbers, swift3, formatter, nsnumberformatter

I have a `UITextField` where the user should type a float number. I want to check that such number has a certain format I receive, for instance "dddd.dd", where "d" is a digit. The format could change at any moment, since I receive it as input as well, so for example I may want to check at another moment that "," character is used for decimals, to say another example.

Taking into account that the `text` you read from the `UITextField` is of `String` type (optional), what should be the best way to accomplish this?

- A predicate with the format provided. Then evaluate the input string. Then converting to number.
- Try to convert to number. If success (how characters for separating decimals would be handled this way?), then check the format with `NumberFormatter`?
- Any other and/or better way?

Comment: If you dont have so many formats try regular expression to validate the input base on situation then covert it to number. Like you suggested, the first way.

Comment: are you willing to restrict users to not register anything other than number?

Comment: @SahebRoy yes, in such text field I only expect numbers (and thousands and decimal separators)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546?s=1|0.1074#29783546

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in `viewDidLoad` or assign delegate to the textfield to self

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   self.txtFieldName.delegate = self;
}
```

Now implement this delegate method -

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == self.txtFieldName)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"01234567989."] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

This will enable yout textfield to only take numbers from 0-9 and .(decimal).