# Trying to convert String to Currency with fatal error result

Tags: ios, swift, currency-formatting

I'm trying to create a simple function that converts a string into the local currency of the user.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
func decimalFormat(stringNumber:String) -> Decimal{
    print("\(stringNumber) is the number being passed")
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)
    print("\(number!) is the number")

    let amount = number?.decimalValue
    return amount!
}
```

For some reason I'm getting the unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value.

the first print works and gives me back what I pass into the function

```
decimalFormat("5.4")
print("\(stringNumber) is the number being passed") -> 5.4
```

So I think the error is coming from this line, just not sure why as I don't think there is an Optional Value you there to unwrap:

```
let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)
```

Comment: `5.4` is not a valid currency string. A currency string has a currency symbol. Use `.decimal` as the `numberStyle` if you wish to parse non-currency number strings.

Comment: Your crash is on the 2nd `print` line because you are force-unwrapping a nil variable. Don't do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546#29783546

Comment: Please update your question with what you expect the inputs and outputs of the function to be. The function currently returns a Decimal, but that is not a formatted currency. Or are you trying to convert from one currency to another? Your question is not clear.