# NumberFormatter for currencies strings with different formatting?

Tags: ios, swift, string, number-formatting, nsnumber

I am writting `CurrencyNumberFormatter` that will take `String` or `NSNumber` and convert it to expected result with respect of current `Locale`.

This is my solution.

```
final class CurrencyNumberFormatter {
    /// Locale of a `CurrencyNumberFormatter`.
    var locale: Locale
    /// numberFormatter of a `CurrencyNumberFormatter`.
    private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter
    /// Initializes a `CurrencyNumberFormatter` with a `Locale`.
    init(locale: Locale = .current) {
        self.locale = locale
        self.numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        self.numberFormatter.locale = self.locale
        self.numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        self.numberFormatter.isLenient = true
    }
    /// Converts a String to a `NSumber`.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - string: string to convert.
    /// - Returns: `NSumber` represenation.
    func number(from string: String) -> NSNumber? {
        return self.numberFormatter.number(from: string)
    }
    /// Converts a NSumber to a `String`.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - number: nsnumber to convert.
    /// - Returns: `NSumber` represenation.
    func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        return self.numberFormatter.string(from: number)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let currensy =  CurrencyNumberFormatter()
currensy.number(from: "1000.25")  // 1000.25
currensy.number(from: "1,000.25") // 1000.25
currensy.number(from: "1.000,25") // nil  -> 1000.25
currensy.number(from: "1'000,25") // nil  -> 1000.25
currensy.number(from: ",25")      // 25   -> 0.25
currensy.number(from: ".25")      // 0.25
```

How can I handle cases with **"1.000,25", "1'000,25" , ",25"** ?

Comment: None of your examples are currency, they are simple decimals formatted in different locales.

Comment: @rmaddy In this example I remove part with currency symbols to highlight issue. In my case user can paste info $1'000,25 and it is in US locale.

Comment: As I said, the numbers use different locales. You only attempt to use the current user’s locale.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk That should be handled by the `NumberFormatter` based on the locale. Or are you looking to accept those values in _all_ locales? (Also, it's "Currency", not "Currensy")

Comment: @ItaiFerber yes you are right I am searching way how can I check value in all locales. Thx for typo. But is It efficient to check all locales ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk What do you expect to have happen when someone types in "1,000" or "1.000"? "1,000" in my locale means 10^3 while "1.000" means 1^1, vs. for someone in a different locale, the expectations could be swapped.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Honestly, it would be best to leave things localized as they are. It would be _really_ confusing for me to enter "$1,000" and have that be parsed as "$1", or type in "$1.000" and have it be parsed as "$1000"...

Comment: @ItaiFerber In my case I need to convert "$1,000"  to NSNumber that is 1000. So the info "1'000,25" -> 1000.25

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Replace all occurrences of `,` and `'` with `.` and then remove all but the last one. This is going to be wrong for many locales, but if you don't care...

Comment: @ItaiFerber but if I set only for example US locale and will try to prepare all string to US locale format I will receive clear NSNumber?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546?s=1|16.9905#29783546

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I'm not sure what you mean by that. If the user locale doesn't matter and you're looking to parse these strings in the same way in _all_ locales, just get rid of the `Locale` altogether. Set it to `en_US_POSIX`, convert the strings to US format always, and parse like that.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I got this thx for help.

Comment: @LeoDabus I will take look thx for help.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Note that not all countries currencies have fractional digits. The link I posted will consider the locale when determining the number of fraction digits