# Swift String: append 0s after decimal separator

Tags: swift, string

I need to append 0, 1, or 2 `0`s to a string, depends on its decimal separator, so that

- "100", "100." and "100.0" becomes "100.00"
- "100.8" becomes "100.80"
- "100.85" remains unchanged

I could find the decimal separator and check its distance to end `endIndex` of the string, but is there an easier way of doing it?

`NumberFormatter` does this, but the actual string I have, isn't a plain number that can go through a formatter.

For example:

`let amount = "123,456,789"`

then formatted amount should be "123,456,789.00"

assumption:

the given string has at most one decimal separator with at most two decimal places

So there can't be string like: "123.4.4.5"

Also I want to use the decimal separator from `NumberFormatter().decimalSeparator`

Comment: @rmaddy Yes it does, however the actual string isn't a plain number, it's number with something else.

Comment: can you give an example of that too?

Comment: You need to post relevant code. Show what you really have and what you really need in addition to what you tried and what issues you are having.

Comment: What if the string is "123.4567" or "1,234.567" or "Price: 1€ for a " ?

Comment: Also, do you want to do that in a locale sensitive way or do you always use a "." as the decimal separator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546?s=1|40.9891#29783546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the string through a decimal formatter to get the underlying number, and then back again through the formatter to get a formatted string:

```
let amount = "123,456,789"
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
let number = formatter.number(from: amount)
let newAmountString = formatter.string(from: number!)  //"123,456,789.00"
```

(You should check that number is not `nil` before force unwrapping it, with `if let`or `guard`)

You could wrap this in a function:

```
func zeroPadding(toString: String) -> String? {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    guard let number = formatter.number(from: toString) else {
        return nil
    }
    return formatter.string(from: number)
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
zeroPadding(toString: "123,456,789")         //"123,456,789.00"
zeroPadding(toString: "123,456,789.0")       //"123,456,789.00"
zeroPadding(toString: "123,456,789.10")      //"123,456,789.10"
zeroPadding(toString: "123,456,789.123")     //"123,456,789.12"
zeroPadding(toString: "123.4567")            //"123.46"
zeroPadding(toString: "Price: 1€ for a ")  //nil
```

Or define it as an extension on **String**:

```
extension String {
    func withZeroPadding() -> String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        guard let number = formatter.number(from: self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return formatter.string(from: number)
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
"123.4.4.5".withZeroPadding()    //nil 
"12.".withZeroPadding()          //"12.00"
"123,456,789".withZeroPadding()  //"123,456,789.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the following code snippet I have tested on Playground, it can be achieved more smartly but for now it is working.**

```
//let amount = "123,456,789.545222323"
//let amount = "123,456,789."
let amount = "123,456,789"
let removeSpaces = amount.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")


if removeSpaces.count > 0
{
let arrSTR = removeSpaces.components(separatedBy: ".")
if  arrSTR.count > 1
{
    var strAfterDecimal = arrSTR[1]
    if strAfterDecimal.count >= 2
    {
        strAfterDecimal = strAfterDecimal[0..<2]
    }else if strAfterDecimal.count != 0
    {
        strAfterDecimal = "\(strAfterDecimal)0"
    }else
    {
        strAfterDecimal = "00"
    }
    let finalSTR = String("\(arrSTR[0]).\(strAfterDecimal)")
    print("Final with Decimal - \(finalSTR)")
}else
{
    let finalSTR = String(arrSTR[0] + ".00")
    print("Final without Decimal - \(finalSTR)")
}
}

extension String {
subscript(_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
    let idx1 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, range.lowerBound))
    let idx2 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: min(self.count, range.upperBound))
    return String(self[idx1..<idx2])
}
}
```