# NSDecimalNumber from user input

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

I'm trying to get conversion fro user entered 
money strings to NSDecimalNumber

```
var nsdecimalNumberFromUserInput: NSDecimalNumber? {
    let parsed = NSDecimalNumber(string: self, locale: Locale.current)
    if parsed == .notANumber {
        return nil
    }
    return parsed
}
```

UIKeyboardType == .numberPad in UITextField
somehow displays either . or , depending on
the device and ios version (12.4[.1] & 13 beta 8).
All current locales set to Belarus.

What's a reliable way to parse money regardless
of the curved balls .numberPad sends my way?

The decimal separator in the above mentioned locale is , (comma)

Thanks

Comment: Use `NumberFormatter` to parse user-entered decimal numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift/29783546

Comment: Is the question about the decimal separator that appears on the keyboard (which, AFAIK, doesn’t even show up with `.numberPad`, but rather only `.decimalPad`)? Or is the question how to convert the string in the text field to `NSDecimalNumber` (or perhaps preferable, `Decimal`)? By the way, the behavior of all of this depends upon the localization settings in your project as well as on the respective simulators...

Comment: Rob, it's both about the proper keyboard and about a string to [NS]Decimal[Number] conversion that can handle improper separators.