# How can I add custom textField to my alert?

Tags: ios, swift

I can add textField to my alert as shown below using `alert.addTextField()`

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Subtitle", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addTextField()
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
            print(alert.textFields?[0].text ?? "")
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, if I have a custom textField, like CurrencyField as shared in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/3286489, how could I add that to my alert (instead of just having a generic TextField)?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j37qi3uv2l0x3sf/Alert%20Currency%20Field.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Holy Path

The Apple-given API doesn't allow for you to use a custom subclass of `UITextField`. It does, however, allow you to customize the `UITextField`:

```swift
alert.addTextField { textField in
    // customize text field
}
```

You'll have to try and port the functionality of your `CurrencyView` over, having only access to the APIs available by default on `UITextField`.

## The Unholy Path

**⚠️ Disclaimer: This is a Bad Idea. Using vendor APIs in ways they weren't intended to makes your code and application less stable.**

Now that we've got that out of the way: you could also add a view directly to the default `UITextField`. You'd have to disable interaction/editing on the original `UITextField`, though, and make sure it only goes to your custom text field.

If you *really* wanted to go to the dark side, you could swizzle `UITextField` and force your `CurrencyView` to be initialized, but, once again, this is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Excellent explanation @mattsven. Indeed by looking at the `open class UIAlertController : UIViewController`, doesn't seem to have a way to custom it... even the `open var textFields: [UITextField]? { get }` is set to `get` only.

Comment: What I mean `custom it` above, refers to assigned a custom made UITextField... sorry for the confusion