# Keep getting error when checking to see if Tip and PriceTxt are empty in Swift

Tags: swift, null, calculator

When entering for the the value for the Tip and the PriceTxt I want to check if it's empty first and return the "Add numbers" if it is but I get the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var PriceTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Tip: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalFinal: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        totalFinal.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func Calcualte(_ sender: Any) {
       if  (PriceTxt.text!) == nil || (Tip.text!) == nil
       {
           totalFinal.text = "Add numbers"
       }
       else {
          let price = Double(PriceTxt.text!)!
          let tipPer = Double(Tip.text!)!
          let TipMult =  price * (tipPer/100)
          let TipFinal = Double((round(100*TipMult)/100) + price)
          totalFinal.text = "$\(TipFinal)"
      }   
   }
}
```

Comment: `UITextField`'s text property will never be nil. Its default value is an empty string. `totalFinal.text = "Add numbers"` will never be executed

Comment: You should use a custom text field to avoid having to check its value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Comment: So then how I check if nothing is entered?

Comment: Check the link above. There is a sample project there as well

Comment: The default value will be zero and the user wont be able to add anything else other than numbers to it

Comment: I still can't seem to figure it out

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: @koen he is forcing the text to be converted to Double. If the field is empty or if it has an invalid value  it will crash. `let price = Double(PriceTxt.text!)!` 
          `let tipPer = Double(Tip.text!)!`

Comment: line 29 is the error

Comment: @JayAhmed You need to use `CurrencyField` instead of a regular `UITextField`. If you need to check its value you can access the field properties `decimal` or `doubleValue`

Comment: There is no line 29 :)

Comment: kkkk OP didn't post the copyright lines

Comment: Sorry! I was looking at my IDE          `let price = Double(PriceTxt.text!)!`

Comment: How would I make the conversion?

Comment: See the link from @LeoDabus.

Comment: I'm new to swift so I'm trying to make the conversation

Comment: @JayAhmed sure. The learning curve is steep. But take some time and check the sample project there. All you need is the `CurrencyField.swift` file copied to your project and after adding a textfield to your storyboard use the inspector to change from UITextField to CurrencyField

Comment: `if  (PriceTxt.text!) == "" || (Tip.text!) == ""`   This worked O.O

Comment: @JayAhmed no need to add parentheses. You can use `UIKeyInput` property `hasText`. Btw it is Swift naming convention to name your objects starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: `if !priceTxt.hasText || !tip.hasText {`

Comment: Note that if you use a regular text field the user can still paste regular text on it even if you change the keyboard type.

Comment: I wasn't looking for optimal solution I just wanted something that worked :D

Comment: @JayAhmed glad you solved