# How to format input currency (from right to left) on a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In a `TextField` I have a initial text `0.00` then how can I format the typed value once the user start typing in Flutter? I'm currently usig the [flutter_money_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_money_formatter) package but I can't get the expected behaviour.

For example, I want the following behaviour if user types the number: `1.800.45`:

When the user taps 1. We should have `0.01`
When the user taps 8. We should display `0.18`
When the user taps 0. We should display `1.80`
When the user taps 0. We should display `1.800`
When the user taps 4. We should display `1.800,4`
When the user taps 5. We should display `1.800,45`.

My current code:

```dart
    class _MoneyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
      TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          style: TextStyle(color: context.primaryColor),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          inputFormatters: [
            TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
              // remove characters to convert the value to double (because one of those may appear in the keyboard)
              String newText = newValue.text.replaceAll(MoneyTextFormField._cents, '')
                  .replaceAll('.', '')
                  .replaceAll(',', '')
                  .replaceAll('_', '')
                  .replaceAll('-', '');
              String value = newText;
              int cursorPosition = newText.length;
              if (newText.isNotEmpty) {
                value = formatCurrency(double.parse(newText), fractionDigits: 0);
                cursorPosition = value.length;
              }
              return TextEditingValue(
                  text: value,
                  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: cursorPosition)
              );
            }),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

The function to format the value:

```dart
      /// Format the giving value and return the value as String
      /// Note: the parameter should be a int or double
      static String formatCurrency(num value,{int fractionDigits = 2}) {
        ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value, 'value');
        return FlutterMoneyFormatter(
          amount: value.toDouble(),
          settings: MoneyFormatterSettings(
            thousandSeparator: '.',
            decimalSeparator: ',',
            fractionDigits: fractionDigits
          ),
        ).output.nonSymbol;
      }
```

Note: this is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift) because the solution does not work for Flutter.

Comment: can you please answer one of my Questions its similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915863/timer-formatter-right-to-left-in-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution for this using the Intl package. Just use the `formatCurrency` method bellow and everything will be fixed.

Note: The value should always be in cents. That is why we divide it by 100 to give us the cents and pass the result into the formatter.

```dart
  static String formatCurrency(num value,{int fractionDigits = 2}) {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value, 'value');

    // convert cents into hundreds.
    value = value / 100;

    return NumberFormat.currency(
      customPattern: '###,###.##',
        // using Netherlands because this country also
        // uses the comma for thousands and dot for decimal separators.
      locale: 'nl_NL'
    ).format(value);
  }
```

Comment: Hi! i also had the same problem. Can you tell me where this function to be implement? in controller or inputFormatter?

Comment: Pass the returned value by this method in the formatter.

Comment: Can you show the full implementation for this in the formatter?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide complte code. It is a bit confusing how to use this solution and where

Comment: I've provided a standalone static function that you can simply copy & paste anywhere and use it, so I'm not sure what you mean by "complete code"

Answer (score 3):

You can use this way.

```
  bool isFirst = true; 


TextFormField(
                  controller: addAmountController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    String newValue = value.replaceAll(',', '').replaceAll('.', '');
                    if (value.isEmpty || newValue == '00') {
                      addAmountController.clear();
                      isFirst = true;
                      return;
                    }
                    double value1 = double.parse(newValue);
                    if (!isFirst) value1 = value1 * 100;
                    value = NumberFormat.currency(customPattern: '###,###.##').format(value1 / 100);
                    addAmountController.value = TextEditingValue(
                      text: value,
                      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value.length),
                    );
                  },
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$`import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

                      onChange: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              value = NumberFormat.currency(
                                      name: "", decimalDigits: 0)
                                  .format(int.parse(value));
                              _price.value = TextEditingValue(
                                text: value,
                                selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                                    offset: value.length),
                              );
                            });
                          }
```

Comment: Please avoid sharing code that does not compile and without describing why it works.