# Programatically trigger editingChanged for a UITextField

Tags: swift

I want to Programatically trigger `.editingChanged` for a `UITextField`

Defining the `UITextField` as:

```
let test = UITextField()
```

I've tried the following:

```
    test.pressesChanged(Set(_immutableCocoaSet: UIPress()), with: .some(UIPressesEvent()))
    test.didChange(.replacement, valuesAt: IndexSet(), for: \.text)
    test.didChange(NSKeyValueChange(rawValue: 0)!, valuesAt: IndexSet(), for:  \.text)
    UITextField.didChangeValue(forKey: \.text)
    test.didChangeValue(for: \.text)
    test.didChangeValue(for: \.touch)
    UIControl.Event.editingChanged
```

I suspect there is a solution using `test.Event.editingChanged` but I can't seem to find it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `test.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)`.
Is this what you need?