# Swift show price depends on Locale

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, decimal, locale

I am getting a string value that represents a price. I want to convert it to another string with specific precision and format it according to a current device Locale.

```
Decimal(string: "123,4567", locale: NSLocale.current)?.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(precision)))
```

This code works for the german language and the output is **"123,45"**. But if I switch to English the output is **"123.00"**. The problem is with the dot instead of the comma. Any ideas how to fix it and show the correct number **"123.45"**?

Comment: well, looks like it is a better solution to use NSFormatter.numberStyle = .currency for this use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to format your decimal number to be displayed using a specific currency what you need is `Decimal.FormatStyle.Currency`. It will automatically discard the excess of precision length:

```
let valueString = "1234,5678"
let decimalLocale: Locale = .init(identifier: "de_DE")
let currencyLocale: Locale = .init(identifier: "en_US")  // or current (used US locale just for demonstration purposes)
if let decimal = Decimal(string: valueString, locale: decimalLocale),
    let currencyCode = currencyLocale.currencyCode {
    let currencyStyle: Decimal.FormatStyle.Currency = .init(code: currencyCode, locale: currencyLocale)
    let currencyFormatted = decimal.formatted(
        currencyStyle.rounded(rule: .towardZero)
    )
    print(currencyFormatted)  // "$1,234.56\n"
}
```

**edit/update**:

I usually don't like manipulating strings but if your source doesn't have a specific format where sometimes de decimal separator is a comma and sometimes a period you need to replace your string comma with a period before converting it to Decimal:

```
let valueString = "1234,5678"
let currencyLocale: Locale = .init(identifier: "en_US")  // or current (used US locale just for demonstration purposes)
if let decimal = Decimal(string: valueString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")),
    let currencyCode = currencyLocale.currencyCode {
    let currencyStyle: Decimal.FormatStyle.Currency = .init(code: currencyCode, locale: currencyLocale)
    let currencyFormatted = decimal.formatted(
        currencyStyle.rounded(rule: .towardZero)
    )
    print(currencyFormatted)  // "$1,234.56\n"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is almost what I need. The one problem is if the number is separated by a dot, instead of a comma ("1234,5678") the result in my case for en_US is $1,234.00. And same for en_DE, if it is separated by a dot("1234.5678") -> 1.234,00 €

Comment: Can you show where is your value coming from? Is it coming from a text field? Check this post [How to input currency format on a text field (from right to left) using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865)

Comment: sure, it is coming from a json file -> "avg_price": "0.0055"

Comment: ok so you have no control over its format? Does your json contain the locale information?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: and also no locale information in the json file. Only the price in a format of "123.45"

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski check my last edit

Answer (score 1):

The locale used for the input string must match the format of the string, so if it is a German format then use a German locale

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
let string = Decimal(string: "123,4567", locale: locale)?
    .formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(precision)))
```

This uses Locale.current (Swedish in this example) for the output

> 123,46

Since this is a price here is a currency example

```
let string = Decimal(string: "123,4567", locale: .current)?
    .formatted(.currency(code: "EUR")
        .precision(.fractionLength(2))
        .rounded(rule: .down)
        .locale(.current))
```

> €123,45

Comment: Thanks, I see. So first of all I need to get a proper string-price to be able to format it to a Local I need? If it is "123,4567" I basically can not format it to $ US format 1,123.45?

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski Yes you can (although your example doesn't match). You do it in two steps as I have shown in the answer. See the last example where I use a locale for the output, change from `.current` to the one you want. I used `.current` in the example because that is the locale the user has selected

Comment: I also noticed that prices such as 0.2460 are represented as 0,0000. Do you have an idea how to fix it? Is NSNumberFormatter is a better way to work with the prices?

Comment: My problem general problem is that I have to use the regional location of the device for formatting. I am getting the price as a string in the format "1298,99" and need to represent it in Germany to 1.298,99 € and in the USA to $1,298.99. So I can not hard code any value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just need to use locale.currencyCode :)

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood you a little then. I thought the original string was always a specific currency but it is the users currency.