# SwiftUI Overwrite Text as typing

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TextField that defaults it's value to `00:00.0`. If a user were to click on the field and start typing, as it is right now if they would type a 7 the value would display `700:00.0`. I want the typing to overwrite the value, from left to right, such that if a user types a 7 then the value would be `00:00.7` and then if they type a 6, 3, 4, 3, 6 in that order it would be `763:43.6`. Is this possible in SwiftUI, and if so does anyone have suggestions as to how?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Swift so can you elaborate? How would I use a formatter to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native SwiftUI solution for this. However, there is one for `UITextField`s as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782982/how-to-input-currency-format-on-a-text-field-from-right-to-left-using-swift). You can use the `UITextField` by wrapping it in a `UIViewRepresentable`. The example is focusing on currency inputs but can flexibly adjusted to your number format by using the appropriate NumberFormatter.

Answer (score -1):

Please try, my understanding steps:-

1. We create a custom OverwritingTextField that takes a binding to a text value.
2. We use the onEditingChanged modifier to track when the text field is being edited.
3. Inside the onChange modifier, we filter the text to ensure that it only contains valid characters (numbers, colon, and period).
4. This way, we prevent unwanted characters from being added. W hen the user types, the text field's value will be overwritten from left to right, as you described.

   ```
    struct OverwritingTextField: View {
        @Binding var text: String
        @State private var isEditing = false

        var body: some View {
            TextField("00:00.0", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                self.isEditing = editing
            })
            .onChange(of: text) { newText in
                if self.isEditing {
                    // Ensure that the text only contains numeric characters and up to one colon and one period
                    let filteredText = newText.filter { "0123456789:.,".contains($0) }
                    self.text = filteredText
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var inputValue = "00:00.0"

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                OverwritingTextField(text: $inputValue)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()

                Text("Input Value: \(inputValue)")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }

    @main
    struct MyApp: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: I don't believe any overwriting is happening here, just data validation. I tried inserting this into my code and it only appended the numbers onto the end, however it does prevent incorrect characters from being included so thank you for that

Comment: This doesn't seem to fulfill the requirements as the textfield is a) not being filled from left to right as requested, b) the format is not validated, c) you can e.g. delete the colons and points instead of keeping 00:00.0, d) you can add more than 5 digits etc...